# SQL Server - Incorrect syntax near ELSE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with my SQL code for tickets orders, everything was working, until I added those UPDATE statements. After I added UPDATE statements every ELSE is being underlined with definition `Incorrect syntax near ELSE`. Is there anything bad with the code syntax itself or could the update statements be made by trigger? I'd be glad if anyone helped:)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ObjednaniVstupenek(@pocetNormal int, @pocetVip int, @akceID int, @email nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP (@pocetVip) * FROM Vstupenky WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'VIP')
        IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP (@pocetNormal) * FROM Vstupenky WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'normal')
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Zakaznici WHERE Email = @email)
                IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Akce WHERE AkceID = @akceID)
                    INSERT INTO Objednavky(Zaplaceno, ZakazniciID)
                    VALUES(1, (SELECT ZakazniciID FROM Zakaznici WHERE Email=@email))
                    UPDATE Vstupenky
                    SET ObjednavkyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Platna = 1
                    WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'VIP' AND VstupenkyID in
                    (
                        select top (@pocetVip) * from Vstupenky
                    )
                    UPDATE Vstupenky
                    SET ObjednavkyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Platna = 1
                    WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'normal' AND VstupenkyID in
                    (
                        select top (@pocetNormal) * from Vstupenky
                    )
                ELSE
                    PRINT 'Taková akce neexistuje'
            ELSE
                PRINT 'Takový email není zaregistrovaný. Prosím, nejdřív se registrujte.'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Není dostatek normálních vstupenek'
    ELSE
    PRINT 'Není dostatek VIP vstupenek'
END
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: What is this trying to do? `select top (@pocetVip) * from Vstupenky`

Comment: You do realise without any defined `begin-end` blocks your `if`s are only effective for your `insert`; everything else will execute regardless.

Comment: There's an update and two inserts within what you appear to want as a single block. Wrap them in `begin`/`end`. Indentation isn't enough.

Comment: `EXISTS(SELECT TOP (@pocetVip) * FROM Vstupenky` makes no sense, as `EXISTS` only checks for one row, so the `top` is useless, likewise `*` is useless and may as well be `1` or `NULL`. Similarly `VstupenkyID in (select top (@pocetVip) * from Vstupenky` also is wrong, as you need to compare to a single column, not `*`. Also why not combine those two `UPDATE` statements into one using `OR`? And why not combine all the `IF`s into one using `AND`?

Answer (score 1):

If statements need begin/end if they "contain" more than 1 SQL statements.

This should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ObjednaniVstupenek(@pocetNormal int, @pocetVip int, @akceID int, @email nvarchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP (@pocetVip) * FROM Vstupenky WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'VIP')
        IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP (@pocetNormal) * FROM Vstupenky WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'normal')
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Zakaznici WHERE Email = @email)
                IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Akce WHERE AkceID = @akceID)
                    begin
                        INSERT INTO Objednavky(Zaplaceno, ZakazniciID)
                        VALUES(1, (SELECT ZakazniciID FROM Zakaznici WHERE Email=@email))
                        UPDATE Vstupenky
                        SET ObjednavkyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Platna = 1
                        WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'VIP' AND VstupenkyID in
                        (
                            select top (@pocetVip) * from Vstupenky
                        )
                        UPDATE Vstupenky
                        SET ObjednavkyID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), Platna = 1
                        WHERE Platna = 0 AND Verze = 'normal' AND VstupenkyID in
                        (
                            select top (@pocetNormal) * from Vstupenky
                        )
                    end
                ELSE
                    PRINT 'Taková akce neexistuje'
            ELSE
                PRINT 'Takový email není zaregistrovaný. Prosím, nejdřív se registrujte.'
        ELSE
            PRINT 'Není dostatek normálních vstupenek'
    ELSE
    PRINT 'Není dostatek VIP vstupenek'
END
```